# Why is UV editor not same size?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have these 2, almost identical soda cans.
Why is the UV Editors, not even close to the same size? (see linked photos)
Is this normal, or have I done something wrong?
[image]
[image]

*Im new to blender :D*

Have a nice friday! : DD

- Jona

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi :D, what you mean, the hole blender file or? - Jona

Comment: You can share the whole Blender file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.

Comment: I added the blender file now! Ty :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second object is unwrapping strangely because it is suffering from *Non-Uniform Scale* (It has been scaled in object mode without scale being applied). To fix, select the object in object mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (apply) and select *Scale*:

[image: Scale]

Also - in the file you provided, the smaller can lacks a seam along the side, as well as around the bottom "cap".

Comment: Hi Christopher. I appreciate your help! :D

Do you know why there is so much difference in the scale of these? (See link)https://imgur.com/a/OigGg5l

Comment: Yes - it's because of the reason I mentioned in my answer, I believe. Apply the scale (and add the seams if necessary) and unwrap again, and they should be a pretty close match.

Comment: Oh - Now it works, thanks! The only thing im wondering about now, is that it rotated 90 degrees. Do you have an idea why? Photo: https://imgur.com/a/cpcdBIl - thanks again, Helped a lot <3!

Comment: Not sure. Probably has to do with one mesh missing an end cap. If it's a problem, just select the whole UV and rotate by 90.